# PHP form file upload to Mysql and to server

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am hoping that somone can help me with a little propject i am working on.

The basics of it is that i have a PHP form with a file upload which i want to to submit to mysql and also upload the file to my uploads folder so its on the server.

I currently have all PHP form set up and submitting all the text to mysql the bit i am struggling with is the file upload part to the server and linking the uploaded file to the mysql. I hope this makes sense.

This is the code i have so far:

```
    <!-- PHP CONNECTION -->
<?php include 'db-connect.php';

$sql="INSERT INTO invoices (companyname, email, address, price, file)
VALUES
('$_POST[companyname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[price]','$_POST[file]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "Project created";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If anyone can help me out would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use input type="file" and in php, use $_FILES instead of $_POST,
 
Dont forget to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to form.**
**Create a folder and add the target path and filename in $filename**(here its FOLDER)

```
<!-- your html input type must be file -->
<input type="file" name="file"/>



<?php
include 'db-connect.php';
if($_FILES["file"]["error"]>0)
{
    echo "FILE ERROR";
    die();
}
$filename = "FOLDER/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
// move file to a folder
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filename)) { // change target path
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    die();
}
$sql="INSERT INTO invoices (companyname, email, address, price, file)
VALUES
('$_POST[companyname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[price]','$filename')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Project created";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it seams to be uploading to the server now. However i am getting this error. Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near './f10/uploads/test.pdf)' at line 3

Comment: add ' in $filename, answer updated... :) change $filename in query to '$filename'

Comment: Wow thank you so much, and quick responce much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should upload file at your server first and then insert the address into database like this simple upload code :

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $image= $_POST['image'];    
    $sid = "usr1";
    if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
        $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
        if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($ext == "png") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($ext == "gif") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/gif") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 550000)) {
            $midname = "test" ;
            $filename2 = $sid.'_'.$midname.'.jpeg';
            $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/avatars/'.$filename2;
            $filead = 'avatars/'.$filename2;
            if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
                if($image !== ""){
                    unlink($image);
                }
                    echo "<img src=\"$filead\" title=\"pic\"  /><br/>";
                echo "UPLOADED";
            } 
        } else {
            echo  "BIG FILE.";
        }
    }   
}
```

**Note** : ALLWAYS check header of file behind checking extension when you want to upload a file on host.